# dataframe set true after the time that meets specific condition daily

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to set condition column to True after the time at which the price was 20 or higher daily like below.

[image]

I want to avoid using apply function because I got several millions data. I think apply requires too much time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cummax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cummax.html) or [`GroupBy.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumsum.html) per days and compare for greater or equal by [`Series.ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ge.html):

```
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
```

---

```
df['condition'] = df.groupby([df['datetime'].dt.date])['price'].cummax().ge(20)
```

If need test also per `compid`:

```
df['condition'] = df.groupby(['compid', df['datetime'].dt.date])['price'].cummax().ge(20)
```

---

```
print (df)
   compid            datetime  price  condition
0       1 2020-11-06 00:00:00     10      False
1       1 2020-11-06 00:00:10     20       True
2       1 2020-11-06 00:00:20      5       True
3       1 2020-11-07 00:00:00     20       True
4       1 2020-11-07 00:00:10      5       True
5       1 2020-11-07 00:00:20     25       True
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`df.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
In [1306]: import numpy as np

In [1307]: df['condition'] = np.where(df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date).price.cumsum().ge(20), 'TRUE', 'FALSE')

In [1308]: df
Out[1308]: 
   compid            datetime  price condition
0       1 2020-11-06 00:00:00     10     FALSE
1       1 2020-11-06 00:00:10     20      TRUE
2       1 2020-11-06 00:00:20      5      TRUE
3       1 2020-11-07 00:00:00     20      TRUE
4       1 2020-11-07 00:00:10      5      TRUE
5       1 2020-11-07 00:00:20     25      TRUE
```

**OR, if you need `bool` values** in `condition` column, do this:

```
In [1309]: df['condition'] = np.where(df.groupby(df.datetime.dt.date).price.cumsum().ge(20), True, False)

In [1310]: df
Out[1310]: 
   compid            datetime  price  condition
0       1 2020-11-06 00:00:00     10      False
1       1 2020-11-06 00:00:10     20       True
2       1 2020-11-06 00:00:20      5       True
3       1 2020-11-07 00:00:00     20       True
4       1 2020-11-07 00:00:10      5       True
5       1 2020-11-07 00:00:20     25       True
```